# Python - Name is not defined in a function variable?

Tags: python, nameerror

I seem to be somehow screwing up the most basic thing. I have:

```
def function(a, b, c):
    return 'hi'
```

`print(function(a,b,c))` results in a `NameError` for every variable.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The names of the arguments of a function are *local variables*, they are not available as global names. `a`, `b` and `c` exist only *inside* of the function, and receive the values you pass to the function.

You need to create *new variables* or use literal values when calling the function:

```
print(function(1, 2, 3))
```

would work because `1`, `2` and `3` are actual values to pass into the function.